# Convert node js module in to NW JS module

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, node-modules, nw.js

I an using NW JS to create a desktop application ,and i don't want to install node js . I need to convert **https://github.com/ScienceVikings/IconExtractor**
this node module into Node webkit module .
what all are the steps should i follow to do this?